# Modify .bst file of journal of computational chemistry

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am getting this kind of citation style:

> Schultze, P.; Macaya, R. F. and Feigon, J., *J. Mol. Biol.*, 1994, **235**(5), 1532 – 1547

However, I want the following style:

> Schultze, P.; Macaya, R. F. and Feigon, J., *J. Mol. Biol.* **1994**, 235, 1532.

I employ the Journal of Computational Chemistry's `jcc2005` bibliography style. The style file, `jcc2005.bst`, is available on the CTAN at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/jcc

Here is the bib file:

```
@article{SCHULTZE19941532,
title = "Three-dimensional Solution Structure of the Thrombin-binding DNA Aptamer d(GGTTGGTGTGGTTGG)",
journal = "Journal of Molecular Biology",
volume = "235",
number = "5",
pages = "1532 - 1547",
year = "1994",
issn = "0022-2836",
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1006/jmbi.1994.1105",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022283684711053",
author = "Peter Schultze and Román F. Macaya and Juli Feigon",
keywords = "two-dimensional NMR, DNA structure, quadruplex, G-quartet, G-DNA"
}
```